# Parameter specified as non-null kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, null, nullable

i have java code and i change to kotlin, my code is used to display pdf by using pdf-viewer library, i do not understand why my code is error and following error:

> The specified as non-null is null parameter: method
>   kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, inputStream
>   parameters

this is my code

```
    package pdfviewer.pdfviewer

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import java.net.URL

class PdfRender : Activity() {

lateinit var pdfView: PDFView

override fun onCreate( savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.pdf_render)
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
inner class DownloadPdf : AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg strings: String): InputStream? {
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        try {
            val uri = URL(strings[0])
            val urlConnection = uri.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            if (urlConnection.responseCode == 200) {
                inputStream = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream)
            }
        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return inputStream
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(inputStream: InputStream) {
        pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load()
    }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you return in the `doInBackground()` method is nullable.
So, the parameter of `onPostExecute()` should be a nullable type.

i.e., `onPostExecute(inputStream: InputStream)` should have been `onPostExecute(inputStream: InputStream?)`.

Answer (score 0):

inputStream is null in some circumstances. When that null value is passed to onPostExecute, the Kotlin intrinsics method barfs because you have specified the param as non-null.

Tl;dr: change onPostExecute to have a nullable parameter.